# If electrons have less mass than planck mass, do they still exert gravitational force?

Tags: gravity, electrons

If electrons have less mass than planck mass do they still exert gravitational force? What about atoms and other subatomic particles with mass?

Comment: The jury is out - http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0308082v3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know of any reason why they shouldn't.  But we don't know for sure, because the gravitational field produced by a Planck-mass object is too small to measure directly.  The lightest object I know of whose gravitational field has been directly measured was 706 mg (http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_067_10_1963.pdf), which is still 35,000 times the Planck mass.